# What are the node states in yarn?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I want to use `yarn` to track the states of my nodes.  So, I do `yarn node -list` to see my nodes.  And then when I want to list all of the nodes in a certain state, I try to do `yarn node -list -states <State>`.

In the webUI I can click on `nodes` and I can see that sometimes my nodes are `UNHEALTHY`.  Why is it that I cannot do similarly from the command line and do `yarn node -list -states UNHEALTHY` ?

Or, is there a reference that someone can give me that will tell me which `states` are available for me to use with this command `yarn node -list -states <State>`  ?

I could not find it [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#node)

Answer (score 1):

Running the wrong command line

```
yarn node -list -states any
```

give you this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.NodeState.ANY
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.NodeState.valueOf(NodeState.java:27)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.NodeCLI.run(NodeCLI.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.NodeCLI.main(NodeCLI.java:62)
```

So the following enum is Used : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.NodeState
According to your version you can check the values of the Enum. here is the link for [hadoop 2.7.1 NodeState](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/NodeState.java/)

Normally,

```
yarn node -list -states UNHEALTHY
```

should work just fine if you have unhealthy nodes from yarn point of view

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you can find all states directly from yarn project. as example hadoop 2.7.3 version listed states for nodes:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records;

import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience.Public;
import org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceStability.Unstable;

/**
 * <p>State of a <code>Node</code>.</p>
 */
@Public
@Unstable
public enum NodeState {
  /** New node */
  NEW, 

  /** Running node */
  RUNNING, 

  /** Node is unhealthy */
  UNHEALTHY, 

  /** Node is out of service */
  DECOMMISSIONED, 

  /** Node has not sent a heartbeat for some configured time threshold*/
  LOST, 

  /** Node has rebooted */
  REBOOTED;

  public boolean isUnusable() {
    return (this == UNHEALTHY || this == DECOMMISSIONED || this == LOST);
  }
}
```

[yarn node state](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC1/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-api/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/NodeState.java)